# Ubuntu - file permissions getting changed automatically

Tags: ubuntu, security, apache-http-server, svn, file-permissions

I want to be able to update a certain `svn` working copy remotely through `php`. For that, I have given `www-data` user write permission to the `.svn` folder (It is owned by `someuser:www-data`, and I have set directory permissions to `775`).

However, after sometime, permissions on the directory **automatically** get reverted back to `755`.

1) What is causing this and how to fix this?

2) I am bit uncomfortable giving `www-data` user write permissions to the directory. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: 1) Most likely SVN itself. We cannot know with such little details. 2) Why don't you just execute *svn update*?

Comment: Cannot run svn update because it (svn update) needs to create .svn/lock file (for which www-data does not have permission)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, you probably want to setup auditd to monitor the directory for permissions changes:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

> How do I set a watch on a file for auditing?
>
> Let us say you would like to audit a /etc/passwd file. You need to
>   type command as follows:

```
# auditctl -w /etc/passwd -p war -k password-file
```

Regarding your second question, it may be a better idea to give the www user sudo permission to another user to run the svn command alone, this way it can't write out random data there and if you want you could more closely control what it can do to the svn repo.